# Cannot get Ansible to start Excel on Windows Server 2019

Tags: excel, windows, powershell, batch-file, ansible

I am trying to launch an .xlsm file on Windows Server 2019 via Ansible.  I can successfully get Ansible to run a Powershell script on the server via:

> ansible win -m win_command -a "powershell.exe -File C:\code\myTestScript.ps1"

And, I can successfuly write a Powershell script that runs on the server and launches the Excel file:

*excel.ps1*

```
# start Excel
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

#open file
$FilePath = "C:\code\Launcher.xlsm"
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
```

However, when I try getting Ansible to run the excel.ps1 script, the command simply hangs.

After the Ansible command is issued, task manager on the Windows server does reveal that the Excel process starts running, but Excel never appears.  Also, the .xlsm file is supposed to write a log file when opened, but that log file is not being written to.

I have also tried the following:

> ansible win -m win_command -a c:\code\launcher.bat

Where the contents of launcher.bat is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" -e Launcher.xlsm
```

That yields the same results.

I have also tried:

> ansible win -m raw -a c:\code\launcher.bat

as well as

> ansible win -m win_command -a "C:\utils\psexec.exe c:\code\launcher.bat"

In all cases, the Ansible command just hangs.  And, in all cases, if I substitute the script/batch file with a script/batch file that simply copies a test file, Ansible is able to successfully complete those commands.

Is it possible to get Ansible to launch an .xlsm file on Windows Server 2019?  If so, what would the command be?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ansible. If it runs as a system service, make sure to read [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am just trying to run the xlsm in the typical fashion with the GUI (not as a system service.)

Comment: Extract from the above link: `Interactivity with the desktop: Office applications assume that they are being run under an interactive desktop`... which is absolutely not the case when running ansible modules on your target. I have 0 XP with windows so that might not even be possible (or using different concepts than linux...), but roughly, you would have to look for the display used by the current opened gui session of your current user and use it to launch your office app.